# Parameter is Not within its Bound Should Extend

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working with Android Recyclerview. In my main activity I have a public static class named `BlogViewHolder` which extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder. When I am attaching this `BlogViewHolder` to FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in onstart method it is showing error `BlogViewHolder is not within its bound should extend androidx.recyclerview.widget.Recyclerview.ViewHolder` Below is my code. what's wrong I am doing

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

   FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder> // here error is giving
}

//this is BlogViewHolder

public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mview;

    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemView =mview;
    }


    public void setDrop(String drop){

        TextView droplocation=(TextView) mview.findViewById(R.id.tvDrop);
        droplocation.setText(drop);
    }  

}
```

and this what I have in my Build.gradle file

```
 implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:25.0.+"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:1.7.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.krtkush:LinearTimer:v2.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:4.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
implementation 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.5'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.florent37:camerafragment:1.0.7' // Custom camera

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.0' 
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.1.0'
```

Comment: What is the exact `import` statement you have for `RecyclerView` at the top of your class file?

Comment: This is what I have in oncreate method  `mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");
        mBloglist=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.Blog_list);
        mBloglist.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mBloglist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));`

Comment: Look at the very top of the class file for the code you've posted, after the `package` on the very first line. There is a section of `import` statements. What is the exact statement for `RecyclerView`?

Comment: import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

Comment: That's your problem. Compare that to the error message. You need the androidx `RecyclerView`. Also, if that `import` statement doesn't have an error, then that would indicate that you're mixing the old support libraries with the new androidx ones. You don't want to do that. Make sure everything is coming from androidx, and that you've removed all of the old dependencies from the app's `build.gradle`.

Comment: I have added my gradle file dependency in the question.Can you suggest how can i avoid androidx

Comment: Oh, it looks like you're still mostly on the old support libraries. It seems like you either upgraded your Firebase, or are just now adding that, and grabbed a newer version. Androidx is the newest version. Do you really want to stick with the old stuff?

Comment: yes it's an old project, only adding firebase now for a simple feature. it is helpful if I can stick with the old stuff

Comment: Well, [here's a link to the release notes for the version when they switched to androidx](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2019-06-17). You'd have to use a version older than that, but I really do not know if you can do that. That is, I have no idea if those old versions will work with their current API. You might do some research on that before you invest too much time in adopting those old ones, in case it's not feasible.

Comment: only firebase dependency?

Comment: I can't really tell, just from looking at that list, but it is Firebase that's the crux of the current issue. Android Studio should complain, at some point, if you are using incompatible versions, so be on the lookout for that.

Comment: changing firebase database version to `firebase-database:9.2.0` and ui to `ui-database:5.1.0` solved the problem. But Now when I am attaching database reference to the Firebaserecycleradapter like   `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(

               Blog.class,
               R.layout.blog_row,
               BlogViewHolder.class,
               mDatabase
       ) {`  it is giving error like in the screenshot https://imgur.com/a/nCXYhG3

Comment: I think that's [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47243957).

Comment: Thanks for gr8 help. further downgrading the firebase ui version to this com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0  solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Even I had got the same error

`extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder`

extend this in your `BlogViewHolder` class and try, this worked for me